# ¿Como puedo acceder a la URL correcta de mis archivos guardados en storage Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, pdf

mi inconveniente es que no puedo poner la url correcta, o si está correcta no deja acceder a los archivos. Tengo una función que genera pdf´s la cual con esta linea guardo esos pdf´s.

```
  date_default_timezone_set('America/Bogota');
  $date = Carbon::now();
  $datetime = $date->format('d M Y');
  $name_pdf = Carbon::now()->hour.Carbon::now()->minute.Carbon::now()->second.$request->dirigidoa.".pdf";
  $pdf = \PDF::loadView('pdf.vista',['entidad'=>$request->dirigidoa,
                        'contacto'=>$request->persona,
                        'ciudad'=>$request->ciudad,
                        'referencia'=>$request->referencias,
                        'nombres'=>$nombres,
                        'descripcion'=>$descripcion,
                        'condicion'=>$condicion,
                        'created_at'=>$datetime]);
  Storage::disk('public')->put($name_pdf, $pdf->output()); //esta linea me guarda el pdf creado en storage/public
```

recientemente ejecuté el comando:  **php artisan storage:link**  para linkear esa carpeta a /public pero no logro establecer el link correcto en mi vista.

```
  @foreach ($list as $lista)
    <tr class="table-active">
      <td>{{$j++}}</td>
      <td>{{$lista->created_at}}</td>
      <td>{{$lista->entidad}}</td>
      <td>{{$lista->contacto}}</td>
      <td>{{$lista->ciudad}}</td>
      <td>{{$lista->referencia}}</td>
      <td><a href="{{url('/storage')}}/{{$lista->url_pdf}}" target="_blank">Link</a> </td>
    </tr>
  @endforeach
```

no se que puede estar mal he provado con varios formatos de link /storage/public/archivo.pdf , ../storage/app/public/archivo.pdf y nada.

Answer (score 1):

Para obtener el url del archivo en el Storage utilizá:

```
$url = Storage::url('archivo.pdf');
```

Acordate de que, si estás usando el driver *local*, la carpeta tiene que estar ubicada en un lugar que sea accesible públicamente.